# Binding an enum type to a context menu showing all variations with the current ticked

Tags: wpf, binding, enums, contextmenu

How can I bind an enum to a context menu, such that all variations of that enum are shown, and a tick for the currently selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple converter for this task which will convert strings to enum values.
Static methods `Enum.Parse()` and `Enum.GetNames()` will help you.